# ActionScript 3 - objects?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm new to Flash AS3. I started making a game and I am a bit confused. Let's assume that I want to create a game that has multiple levels/modes, how can I do this in an object orientated way?

When i create games in other languages e.g. XNA C#, i create a separate class then create an object of that class within the main class and run the game based on a simple statement.

```
if(player picks second option)
object2.start_level
else
object1.start_level
```

How can this be done is AS3? Are there any Tutorials I could read on, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create your levels and attach them onto the main scene dynamically

```
if(player picks second option)
  addChild(object2);
else
  addChild(object1);
```

In your objects you can link the initialization of the level when the event `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` is distpached.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if I understood correctly your question, you should behave just as you used to in XNA C#: two instances(`object1` and `object2`) of class Level and

```
if(player picks second option) object2.start_level else object1.start_level
```

If I understood you incorrectly feel free to reask and specify your question.

P.S.: you can read about how to create classes in AS3 [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html)